# zeromq: how to do REQ-multiple-REP?

Tags: zeromq

Using zeromq, I basically want to do a 'REQ-multiple-REP' pattern: client sends 1 message to a server, and the server then sends multiple replies until done. The 'multiple replies' are *to that client*: not a general publishment.

I can roll this myself: have a normal REQ-REP socket, and when the server gets a request, it creates a new PUB, replies with the address of that PUB in the reply to the client, and the client then SUBs to the PUB, which the server has already begun putting messages into.

But that feels unwieldy. Is there a better way? Does zeromq already have something cool for this use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something with a XPUB/XSUB partnering a REQ/REP.

These could be permanently set up, i.e. clients and server are all on the same XPUB/XSUB connection. When a client wants to make a request it can send a client-unique subscription message through their XSUB socket. The server reads that and remembers that. The client then sends a REQ which includes the subscription message again as one of the request's fields. The server responds on the REP, and all further server responses are sent through its XPUB using the subscription message it'd previously received from the client to label the responses. All other clients, not subscribed to that, won't get responses not intended for themselves. The client then unsubscribes from those responses (after receiving the last one; the server may have to include a "last response" flag in that last one) by sending an unsub through through its XSUB socket. For the next request it uses a different client-unique ID, just so that the responses to that request can be distinguised from responses from the previous request.

This is still not terribly elegant, but at least it's not setting up / tearing down socket connections all the time.

Pseudo Code - Server. You'll need to read this section of the guide: [Pub-Sub Message Envelopes](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Pub-Sub-Message-Envelopes)

```
while (run)
    zmq_poll(XPUB socket, X REP socket)
    if (ZPUB socket ready)
        zmq_recv(client subscription message)
        if (message was a subscription)
            store subscription info (i.e. the client's unique topic for responses)
        else if (message was unsubscribe)
            forget client's unique topic for responses
    else if (X REP socket ready AND client unique topic received)
        zmq_recv(client request including client topic for responses)
        process the request
        zmq_send(REP socket, first response)
        s_sendmore(XPUB socket, client's unique topic for responses)
        s_send(XPUB socket, second response)
        s_sendmore(XPUB socket, client's unique topic for responses)
        s_send(XPUB socket, third response)
    else if (X REP socket ready AND client unique topic *not* received)
       error condition
    end if
loop
```

and client

```
create unique topic for response (a random, unique string) // Caution - I think there's a length limit
zmq_send(ZSUB socket, '\0x01`+ unique topic string)
zmq_setsockopt(ZSUB socket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, unique topic for responses) // may not be necessary - it's a ZSUB socket, and the socket may have already picked this up from the previous zmq_send().
zmq_send(REQ socket, request including unique topic string)
zmq_recv(REQ socket, first response)
zmq_recv(ZSUB socket, second response)
zmq_recv(ZSUB socket, third response)
zmq_setsockopt(ZSUB socket, ZMQ_UNSUBSCRIBE, unique topic for responses) // this may not be necessary, and the follow line might do the same thing
zmq_send(ZSUB socket, '\0x00`+ unique topic string)
```

Comment: I haven't used xpub/xsub before, am a bit confused: why the need for two 'subscribe' messages? Is the first xsub subscription message necessary?

Comment: @Colin, Maybe not, but I don't know what the innards of the ZMQ lib require. This way XSUB/XPUB is being used as per the docs, and everything will work. It's also a robust setup; the server knows that the client has subscribed to the right topic for the replies and, perhaps more importantly, that the client has not unsubscribed from that topic. The server should read an xsub then a req, and it then writes rep, xpub, xpub...last xpub, then it should see xunsub. Something more "open loop" could probably be done with pub/sub, but with less error checking. Or, something like that!

Comment: or anybody: I'm having trouble discovering how to actually do the above. I can't seem to find any official documentation about the details of xpub/xsub besides a single graphic and 3 paragraphs, with no code, in the guide. Am I missing the trove of actual documentation somehow?

Comment: @Colin, take a look at this API guide: http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-socket. It describes ZMQ_XPUB and ZMQ_XSUB socket types. They're basically the same as PUB and SUB, except you can read subscriptions from XPUB (you can't read from an ordinary PUB), and you can send subscriptions through an XSUB (you can't send anything through an ordinary SUB)

Comment: @Colin, that documentation says they're unidirectional, but that's simply the flow of data. The subscriptions flow the other way. I'll add some psuedo code to the answer...

Comment: @Colin, there, I've added some psuedo code. The `s_send()` and `s_sendmore()` functions are helpers for C/C++ in creating multiple frame messages. See the C example code at http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Pub-Sub-Message-Envelopes.

Comment: ah, there's the api! Thanks, I will work through this.

Comment: @Colin good luck, and please get back to me if you run into trouble :-)

Comment: So @bazza thank you! Some progress and things I've noted: 1) in the pseudocode above, when the client performs the two receives on the ZSUB, it should actually be 4: it will receive first the topic, then the first published message, then the topic again, then the second published message. Maybe this happens because the server is publishing directly on an xpub socket (instead of publishing on a pub socket, routing through xsub/xpub)?

Comment: Second, I've realized that maybe the server doesn't need to know the client topic string before hand, and maybe doesn't care whether the client is already connected or not. If the client is already connected, then it will get all the published messages, and if not it won't - it's problem. And so: maybe I don't need xpub at all.

Comment: @Colin I was supposing that there is more than one client! The unique topic allows for that - client A would be able to receive responses intended for itself, whilst client B (subscribed on a different topic) won't. The XPUB/XSUB are a useful way in which the clients and server can agree on topics for separation. Also, it allows a single client to differentiate between responses for it's different requests. There's no guarantee that the order of delivery to the client on separate sockets (the XSUB and the REQ) will be the same as the server's sending order. The topic-per-req helps with that.

Comment: Hey @bazza not just one client - still have multiple clients. When the client subscribes, you wrote "The server reads that and remembers that" in the description, so that "the server knows that the client has subscribed to the right topic". But I did this: the client still pre-subscribes before the rpc, but the server doesn't know: it will publish regardless of whether a client is subscribed or not, in response to the rpc. Now robustness is the responsibility of the client: simply subscribe before rpc. And no xpub needed: zpub also handles topic filtering. Hope I'm not missing some edge case.

Comment: @Colin Ah, so you have the topic being communicated from client->server in the REQ? That's fine, if you're happy that the server needn't know for sure that the client had actually subscribed. So long as it's the client choosing the topic, and subscribing before it makes the REQ, then that's fine because the client is then able to cope with the race between the REP and the first PUB.

Answer (score 1):

A Dealer/Router pair should work for your use case, where the Request is replaced by Dealer and Reply by Router.

The important part is the Router socket behaviour. Any incoming message will be multipart and contain at least 1 'routing' frame, 1 empty frame and however many content frames you sent.

Any message sent on a dealer will pop the first frame and use that to determine which client to send the message to.

Comment: Any example you suggest?